# AWS: Angular app listening on Port 4200, but not connecting in browser

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently loading a MEAN stack application on Amazon Web Services.  The app consists of a Mongo DB listening on port 27017, A Node listening on port 3000, and a front end angular application listening on port 4200.  When i launch the node server, and i navigate to the awsdomain:3000, a basic index page that i made loads correctly.   When i launch the Angular app( successfully) it says its listening localhost:4200, but is not accessible when i go to the awsdomain:4200.  I have set the custom tcp rules to allow traffic on all three ports, (Mongo, Node, Angular).  I'm new to aws, and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas to why this would happen.

Comment: It seems your angular application is binded to localhost. You need to specify 0.0.0.0 in the listen call.

Comment: That worked.  Thank You!